# AngularJS validation message is not displayed when the field is required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm using angularJs validation in my html form but error message not displayed in form.Code is as follows:

```
<form role="form" name="ContactForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 first-name-txtbox">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName"  placeholder="First Name" required="" />
                             <span ng-show="ContactForm.FirstName.$error.required">
                                 <small class="text-danger">Please enter First Name</small>
                             </span>
                         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set ng-model on your input otherwise it won't work